# Error occured during installation of Arduino

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have MATLAB R2013a and been trying to install the Simulink support package for Arduino hardware but I keep getting the following error:

> "Error installing third party package Arduino software: Invalid zip file "C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2013a\downloads\arduino-1.0-windows.zip"."

and then the installation stops.

Answer (score 0):

There is already an answer by *Shaima Al Hebsi* on [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/121443-error-installing-third-party-package-arduino-software-invalid-zip-file#answer_249683):

> - Install the Hardware support from the Add-ons button in Matlab and wait for the error. Once you get the error cancel and exit the installation.
> - Get Arduino 1.0 (the only version which made it work) from http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/OldSoftwareReleases when you download it you will get it as a zip file having the same name which was shown in the error message arduino-1.0-windows.zip
> - Now go to the directory shown in the error message: C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2013a\downloads\arduino-1.0-windows.zip
>     and replace the existing corrupted arduino-1.0-windows.zip with the new one downloaded recently
> - Disconnect internet connection and again go to Matlab add-ons and try again to install arduino hardware support package It should work this time.